# Acceder a libreria con node_modules fuera de la raiz

Tags: javascript, npm, packages

Tengo un proyecto en php que he realizado en un Modelo Vista Controlador propio. En este MVC tengo la siguiente estructura de directorios:

> - controllers
> - models
> - public
>
>   - css
>   - images
>   - js
>   - .htaccess
>   - **index.php**
> - views
> - vendor
> - **node_modules**
> - composer.json
> - composer.lock
> - package-lock.json
> - package.json

Para instalar las dependencias de php he instalado la carpeta vendor en la raíz del proyecto (el directorio anterior a public) y me gustaría hacer lo mismo con npm y la carpeta node_modules.

El problema es que al llamar a las librerías de node_modules desde algún archivo (todo lo gestiona el index.php) no se encuentran dichas librerías. A las librerías las llamo de la siguiente manera:

```
<script defer src='/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands.js'></script>
    <script defer src='/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid.js'></script>
    <script defer src='/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome.js'> 
</script>
```

Y el error que se me muestra en la consola de navegador es el siguiente:

> GET http://php-mvc-template.localhost/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not found).

Como veréis el programa intenta acceder a node_modules desde la raíz del proyecto que está en public, pero dicha carpeta está mas atrás en el árbol de directorios.

Aunque llame a la ruta de otras maneras tampoco funciona como por ejemplo:

```
<script defer src='../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands.js'></script>
```

Si instalo node_modules en la carpeta public funciona todo perfectamente pero me gustaría instalarlo en la carpeta principal. ¿Qué solución podría tomar?

Comment: Si tienes ti carpeta node modules significa que estás trabajando con nodejs por lo que simplemente puedes requerir tu script con `require("modulo")`

Comment: En mi opinión y de acuerdo a mi experiencia, las dependencias de *desarrollo* deberías compilarlas para *producción*, de hecho, en el ejemplo que muestras se ve que usas la librería *FontAwesome*, la cual puedes usar directamente usando un CDN o servirla tu mismo desde la carpeta `public`, pero para que esté disponible en dicha carpeta sin que la coloques manualmente allí, debes hacer un proceso de compilado (*bundle*) para que todas esas dependencias sean añadidas a tu carpeta `public` de forma programática. Saludos

Comment: Además de lo dicho, que estoy de acuerdo, piensa que sería muy inseguro que desde el cliente se pueda acceder a los archivos detras de lo que se defina como público. Cualquiera podría ver archvos de configuración porejemplo.

Comment: Creo que lo que tienes en node modules es un enlace y jamas te lo va a encontrar, te lo digo por experiencia propia, te recomiendo lo que dice mauricio